# посчитать последовательный индекс элементов опуская вложенность

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Есть примерно такая разметка:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="item">
    item0
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="item">
    item1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item2
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item3
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item4
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item5
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="item">
    item6
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item7
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item8
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item9
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item10
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item11
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item12
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item13
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="item">
    item14
  </div>
</div>
```

визуально они идут в строку друг за другом, мне нужно каждый четвертый .item задать свой стиль, как выбрать эти кратные четырем элементы? при том что мне нужно что бы он не считал каждый `.row` отдельно, а `.item` для него были с последовательным индексом.

пытался `$('.item:nth-child(4n)').css({'clear':'both'});`

но как раз именно тут он считает каждый `.row` заново, как это побороть?

готов услышать любые решения css, js, jq.

Comment: никак, только выбирать все а потом фильтровать

Comment: @Grundy можно услышать ваш вариант  выборки .item а потом присвоение каждому 4.

Comment: почитайте тут: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/counter-increment/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
Array.prototype.reduce.call(document.getElementsByClassName('item'), (i,el) => {
  if(i===4){
    el.classList.add('fourth');
    i=0;
  }
  return i+1;
}, 1);
```

```css
.fourth{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="item">
    item0
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="item">
    item1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item2
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item3
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item4
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item5
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="item">
    item6
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item7
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item8
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item9
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item10
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item11
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item12
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item13
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="item">
    item14
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, забираю.